# How to resolve lint error 'arrow function cannot return an assignment statement'

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my NodeJS the following function gives me an error as `Arrow function cannot return an assignment statement`

```
required.forEach(v => (envs[v] = process.env[v]));
```

I saw similar questions but those questions referring to the situation with like

```
const x = a => this.a = a
```

I don't know for my situation actually how to change as I have `[v]`

Comment: You could use curlies, so that `void` is returned: `required.forEach(v => { envs[v] = process.env[v]; });` ?

Comment: Just don't return the value, it's useless in a `forEach` anyway. Wrap it in `{}`.

Comment: @CherryDT eh, in this case it's completely irrelevant. The linter rule is probably a bit too strict when applied to `forEach`.